# Is it possible to use Azure AD B2C to connect with Instagram?

Tags: c#, azure, instagram, azure-ad-b2c

Is there anyone that had to use Azure AD B2C but had to let users connect with Instagram ? It seems Azure AD B2C doesn't have the capacity to do that yet.

I found no information about this on any search engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**, it is possible to connect Azure AD B2C with Instagram using [Custom Policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-overview-custom).  These policies allow you to configure a custom policy setup that hooks up to any identity provider that supports OpenID Connect (any by extension some OAuth2.0 providers).  Just to clarify, Instagram is not currently supported as an out of the provider, but entirely possible to configure.

There is no sample to do this on Instagram today, but we will begin working on a custom policy sample *today*. Watch for a [code sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=active%20directory%20b2c&type=&language=) & I can update this answer.

Comment: @Daniel...Thanks! I didn't know this (simply went by documentation). Once OP accepts your answer, I will remove mine (it seems I can't remove an accepted answer).

Comment: yes and to provide a little more clarity using custom policies we can federate to identity providers that support SAML as well. Recently we federated B2C to our on-prem IDP using SAML 2.

Comment: @GauravMantri makes sense. We're still chugging away writing new docs to show off all these cool new features, sorry it confused you!

Comment: @DanielDobalian Thanks! I can completely understand about the documentation. Just a minor suggestion: I think it would be helpful to mention this in the FAQs (which I referenced) and include a link to the Github repo where you will be including code samples. BTW, I have flagged my answer for moderator's attention to be deleted. For now I have made it abundantly clear that my answer is incorrect and one should look at your answer :).

Comment: That's a great suggestion, I'll look into adding more detail to that doc about custom policies. Thank you @GauravMantri.

Comment: @Daniel Thanks ! I am going to try this now and come back to you